# "After her" or "after she"?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

> The first time was in March-April 2012, when I was still in Canada visiting family and relatives, and Sandra had returned to Australia. I returned to Australia 3 weeks after she.

It sounds strange, but is it *correct*?

Comment: It's always 'after her'.

Comment: You could say "3 weeks after she did". It's not ungrammatical, but somewhat stilted.

Comment: *after she **did***?

Comment: @MarcosGonzalez Split second! :)

Comment: Oops! I answered just a split-second... after you. Or after you did?  :-))

Comment: Sure, before I (did).

Comment: "I arrived after John." sounds perfect to me, though.

Comment: You don't really need to write "family and relatives". Relatives **are** family. It would be sufficient just to write "visiting family" or "visiting relatives".

Comment: Technically, this is correct; however, to most English speakers, that doesn't sound right. We would normally say "after her" or "after she *did*" while speaking.

Comment: @Daniel If it sounds wrong to most English speakers, then it's not technically correct.

Answer (score 2):

> ... Sandra had returned to Australia. I returned to Australia 3 weeks after she.

This is not correct.

While it may be true that what you **mean** is "I returned to Australia three weeks after she returned to Australia", in this case syntactical form trumps meaning. Formally, bare *SHE* is the entire object of the preposition; it is not apprehended as the subject of an ellipted clause; it must therefore be realized in its objective-case form, *her*.

Nominative-case *she* would be employed after a preposition **only** when it is followed by a verb of which it is the subject—more precisely, when the object of the preposition is a clause of which *she* is the subject.

> Sandra had returned to Australia. I returned to Australia 3 weeks after she ***did***.

This is true in all registers. The most rigorous pedant (e.g. me—or ***I***) would not write *after she* here.

Comment: "Nominative-case she is employed only if it is followed by a verb of which it is the subject."  An exception to this is that the verb "to be" also uses the nominative case as the object: "May I speak to Bob, please?"  "This is he."  "Are you the one who plays the piano?"  "I am he."

Comment: @snailplane I'm sorry, but I'm unable to find anything in the article you post that supports your assertion that "'I am he' is not an example of good English." Can you help me out?  In particular, I'm curious about this from the article, which seems to contradict the assertion: "And we *do* follow that rule to some extent: 'Who are they?' (not 'Who are them?' or "Whom are they?') 'We are they!' (in response to the preceding)."

Comment: @BobRodes I'll delete my old comment, as my views have softened somewhat in the meantime, but I still don't consider "I am he" particularly good English.  What the link was meant to show you was that the rule is spurious and that there's no reason to favor "I am he" over "I am him" on grammatical grounds.  (And no, what you quote does not support your point--it's about "Who are they", not "I am he".)  "I am he" is definitely inferior English (favored by almost zero speakers), but I'm willing to admit that it's grammatical, if over-formal.

Comment: Again, please show me anything in your link that demonstrates that the rule is spurious. I've looked and looked, and can't find anything. (And now you've deleted the link, so I'll have to go googling for it if I want to look any further.)  Also, are you saying that my error is that the rule is true in the plural form but not in the singular?

Comment: @BobRodes (I am only now seeing your original comment) I have edited my answer to make clear that I am speaking only of cases like that OP asks about, where the pronoun follows a preposition.

Comment: @StoneyB I figured as much when I wrote this, but wanted to make the clarification for the OP.